# Python sending each character through a function?

Tags: python, function, loops

So I have this assignment where I need need to ask for user input. Each letter the user inputs will return the NATO alphabet equivalent. e.g. F="FoxTrot". This input is put through a function to get the returned value. I also have several IF statements in the function for specific characters, e.g. 9="niner", -="Dash", any other number/character just returns that character.

The problem I am having is it will at this time only allow one character to be entered. If I try to enter multiple characters it will give me the error "typeerror ord() expected a character but string length # found". I cannot change that ord statement according to the assignment. Because it gives the correct calculation for the NATO alphabet equivalent.

```
def main():
    char = input("Enter license plate tag: ")
    charToWord(char)

def charToWord(char):    
nato = ["Alpha","Beta","Charlie","Delta","Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","India","Juliett","Kilo","Lima","Mike","November","Oscar","Papa","Quebec","Romeo","Sierra","Tango","Uniform","Victor","Whiskey","X-Ray","Yankee","Zulu" ]
work =''

charNum = ord(char) - 65
word = nato[charNum]

if char.isalpha():
   print(word)
if char == "9":
   print("Niner")
if char == "-":
   print("Dash")
else:
   print(char)

return word

main()
```

So I believe I need to be inputting a For loop into my main function? In order for it to pass multiple characters through the charToWord function? However I'm uncertain on how to construct it. 
Any suggestions? 
Thank you.

Comment: [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) - `The for statement is used to iterate over the elements of a sequence (such as a string, tuple or list) or other iterable object:`  A string is a sequence so you can use a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, using `map`:

```
def charToWord(char):    
    nato = ["Alpha","Beta","Charlie","Delta","Echo","Foxtrot","Golf","Hotel","India","Juliett","Kilo","Lima","Mike","November","Oscar","Papa","Quebec","Romeo","Sierra","Tango","Uniform","Victor","Whiskey","X-Ray","Yankee","Zulu" ]
    decode = {w[0]: w for w in nato}
    decode["9"] = "Niner"
    decode["-"] = "Dash"
    return decode.get(char, char)

# ...
list(map(charToWord, "ABC9-9G"))
# ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Charlie', 'Niner', 'Dash', 'Niner', 'Golf']
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could restructure your main() like so:

```
def main():
    userInput = input("Enter license plate tag: ")
    for char in userInput:
        charToWord(char)
```